# creating a different database for each collection in MongoDB 2.2

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 2.2 has a write lock per database as opposed to a global write lock on the server in previous versions. So would it be ok if i store each collection in a separate database to effectively have a write lock per collection.(This will make it look like MyISAM's table level locking). Is this approach faulty?

Comment: Do you want to do this because you are seeing the write lock limit your write throughput rate?

Comment: Yes i have been downloading data from different feeds and then i send batches of bulk inserts to the database and there is not just one program sending those batch inserts but several

Comment: i dont understand the reasons for the close flag

Comment: I understand you are sending bulk inserts to the db, but are you seeing write lock causing problems or do you just *think* that you need to split up collections into separate dbs?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky many times the write lock causes only one write to happen at time. I write in batches of 2000 documents and it takes 5-8 seconds to finish a batch and many times it happens that 2 or more programs are trying to write at the same time to different collections and then write to one collections blocks the others

Comment: seems unlikely - I can write 40,000 documents per second on my laptop into the same collection from multiple threads, and there is only a single write lock in this case.  Unless you are seeing the write lock as being the limiting factor (i.e. your writes are waiting for the write-lock rather than for i/o bandwidth or because they are updating multiple indexes each, etc) splitting things up may not help.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky What is the average size of your document? Do you have indexes. The average size of document in my case is about 1.4 KB and and i have unique indexes so i have to do safe inserts.

Comment: ok, but my main point is "do not assume the single write lock will be a problem" - test it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky All right but considering the above numbers i mentioned do you think that write lock should be a problem?

Comment: no, I don't think it's the write lock. if it's taking longer than it should it could be the design, the i/o, indexes, lack of indexes, or many other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a key limitation to the locking and that is the `local` database. That database includes a the `oplog` collection which is used for replication.

If you're running in production, you should be running with Replica Sets. If you're running with Replica Sets, you need to be aware of the write lock effect on that database.

Breaking out your 10 collections into 10 DBs is useless if they all block waiting for the `oplog`.

Before taking a large step to re-write, please ensure that the `oplog` will not cause issues.

Also, be aware that MongoDB implements DB-level security. If you're using any security features, you are now creating more DBs to secure.

Comment: I got your point but i am not deeply familiar with `oplog` but i think i should get now. Nice point though

Comment: Gates, could you please explain how I can measure locking contention on `oplog` versus my db ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that will work, 10gen actually offers this as an option in their talks on locking.

I probably isolate every collection, though. Most databases seem to have 2-5 high activity collections. For the sake of simplicity it's probably better to keep the low activity collections grouped in one DB and put high activity collections in their own databases.

Comment: Thanks. Can u direct me to some talks or links where i can see more of it?