# Multiple single-collection databases, or database with multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any advantage to using multiple collections within a database, when multiple databases each with a single collection would accomplish the same thing? From what I can gather, using multiple databases reduces lock contention because locks are per-database, so I wonder why you'd ever want to put more than one collection in a single database.

The only downside I've found mentioned is that there's some overhead (~200MB) per database, and that with a large number of databases, OS file handles can become a limitation, but I imagine that if you have enough collections/databases for those to be issues, you've got too many databases. These overheads are bearable in my case; I'd like to know if there's something else I should know about.

EDIT: In my situation there are currently 30 collections spread across 8 databases. I'm asking this question because I think it may be better to make this 30 collections across 30 databases. There's no real reason for the current structure; it was set up by a team who don't know much about databases so picked arbitrarily. It's now used frequently enough for lock contention to be a factor (profiling shows some operations spending >1 second waiting for locks). We'll scale horizontally too, I just saw this as a potential low-hanging fruit since it just means using a different database name for some operations, instead of a different collection name.

Apologies if this has been asked before; the only similar questions I've found have been about whether to use e.g. "a collection per user" which isn't quite the same thing. In my case I have heterogeneous documents which I definitely do want stored in different collections, I'd just like to know whether to store those collections in the same database or not.

Comment: Everything's simpler if it's all in one database. Do you really anticipate such a high level of write activity that lock contention will be a problem?

Comment: I should have said (I'll edit the question) - I already have a few databases, some of which have several collections, some of which have just one or two. Enabling profiling I can see that some operations do spend more then a second waiting on locks, both for reading and writing. How does a single database make things simpler? I already have to specify the collection for every operation, I don't mind also specifying the database. Is there something else besides naming that makes it less convenient?

Comment: Things like the `MongoClient` driver connection pooling being database oriented, driver support for following ObjectId refs, backing up your data.

Comment: Excellent, those are the kinds of things I'm looking for! Thanks, that gives me something to google!

Answer (score 1):

may be duplicate of this: [creating a different database for each collection in MongoDB 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673097/creating-a-different-database-for-each-collection-in-mongodb-2-2)

in my solution I created own database for each large and highload collection, for rest collections I create another common database. Mongodb implements locks on a per-database basis for most read and write operations: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ But locks in mongoDb not so nasty as in SQL.

This solution increase productivity of mongodb for me.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for your answer! May I ask: why do you keep the low-use collections in the same database? Are there settings you set on the database that you'd otherwise have to do for all databases? Which settings? Most customisation looks like it's done at the collection level anyway.

Comment: We use one database for many collection only for convenience. Really we use three databases for low-use collections. They separated only by architecture destinations - for frontend, backend and debug. We don't use any settings for db - all defaults. Now we think about setting custom chunk size for highload databases, but it yet have not done